# why the rewrite of prototype is unsuccess?

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
function DivElement(){
    this.ctor.apply(this,arguments);
}

DivElement.prototype = {
    obj:{
        name:'',
        src:''
    },
    objName:'',
    objSrc:'',

    ctor:function(){
        this.obj.name = arguments[0];
        this.obj.src = arguments[1];
        this.objName = arguments[0];
        this.objSrc = arguments[1];
    }
}

var d1 = new DivElement('a','a.jpg');
var d2 = new DivElement('b','b.jpg');

console.log(d1.obj.src);    //b.jpg
console.log(d2.obj.src);    //b.jpg
console.log(d1.objSrc);     //a.jpg
console.log(d2.objSrc);     //b.jpg
```

The problem is why d1.obj.src is not 'a.jpg'?

And if I rewrite the function ctor like this:

```
ctor:function(){
    this.obj = {name:arguments[0],src:arguments[1]};
    this.objName = arguments[0];
    this.objSrc = arguments[1];
}
```

It works right!

Who can tell me what's happend over there...

Comment: Try adding `var` before `obj =`, then `obj.name =`

Answer (score 1):

The Problemn you have is that the Instances of `DivElement` share the same Object `obj` unless you don't explicitly assign the it as a propertie of you'r Instance.

So whats actually happen is in this Line `this.obj.src = arguments[1];`

You are overwriting the propertie `src` of the Object `obj` which is shadowed by all Instances.

So as soon as you're executing `ctor` the second time, youz are overwriting `d1`'s propertie `src` with the value `a` with the one that `d2` gets initialized with.

`this.objSrc = arguments[1];` is an Own propertie of the instance it self, so each Instance has its own copy, and it doesn't get overwritten in the second execution.

The same applies to `this.obj = {name:arguments[0],src:arguments[1]};` as you are assigning the Object `obj` explicitly to every instance.

Answer (score 0):

Items in the prototype are NOT deep copied for each new object.  So, when you're trying to use `obj.name` from the prototype, there is only one copy of `obj` for all your objects.  Thus, your second object is overwriting the `obj` from the first and the confusion entails.  Prototypes work best for functions or constants and not for objects and arrays.

It would be best to add the `obj` to your instance data in the constructor so there will be a new one for each instance like this:

```
function DivElement(){
    this.ctor.apply(this,arguments);
}

DivElement.prototype = {
    ctor:function(){
        this.obj = {};
        this.obj.name = arguments[0];
        this.obj.src = arguments[1];
        this.objName = arguments[0];
        this.objSrc = arguments[1];
    }
}

var d1 = new DivElement('a','a.jpg');
var d2 = new DivElement('b','b.jpg');

console.log(d1.obj.src);    //b.jpg
console.log(d2.obj.src);    //b.jpg
console.log(d1.objSrc);     //a.jpg
console.log(d2.objSrc);     //b.jpg
```